# ._lib-popup-button-close-icon is undefined after Upgrading to Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2

After upgrading my magento 2.0.7 to magento 2.1.0 via ssh. I encountered this error. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error after upgrading to 2.1, I've managed to fix it by adding the below code to the bottom of the _popups.less within my theme.

I took the code from `lib/web/css/source/lib/_popups.less`, it isn't best practice to duplicate this mixin in this way but it's the only fix I'm aware of.

```
// Fix bug from Luma theme
//  Popup close button use icon
._lib-popup-button-close-icon(
    @_popup-button-close-icon,
    @_popup-icon-font-content,
    @_popup-icon-font,
    @_popup-icon-font-size,
    @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
    @_popup-icon-font-color,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
    @_popup-icon-font-margin,
    @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
    @_popup-icon-font-position,
    @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
) when (@_popup-button-close-icon = true) {
    .lib-button-icon(
        @_icon-font-content: @_popup-icon-font-content,
        @_icon-font: @_popup-icon-font,
        @_icon-font-size: @_popup-icon-font-size,
        @_icon-font-line-height: @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
        @_icon-font-color: @_popup-icon-font-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
        @_icon-font-color-active: @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
        @_icon-font-margin: @_popup-icon-font-margin,
        @_icon-font-vertical-align: @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
        @_icon-font-position: @_popup-icon-font-position,
        @_icon-font-text-hide: @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
    );
}

//  Popup close button reset
._lib-popup-button-close-reset (
    @_popup-button-close-reset
) when (@_popup-button-close-reset = true) {
    .lib-button-reset();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for your solution. I'll try this one on my site. but as I've observed magento 2.1 has many bugs.

Comment: There's always been bugs in Magento, I think there is just more to go wrong with Magento 2 :(

Comment: Yeah :( I just used my backup copy of my site magento 2.0.7, I'll just wait till they fix the bugs in magento 2.1.0 :( sad life :(